# How to add draggable scrollbar to scrollview/listview in Android?

Tags: android, android-listview, scrollbar

I have a listView that uses a customListAdapter created by me. When user scrolls the list, he/she sees scrolling indicator as usual on the right side.

However, I want to show a draggable track-button on the right side, so user will be able to hold that button and quickly scroll through the list.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe the xml values `fastScrollEnabled` and optionally `fastScrollAlwaysVisible` are what you want to set for the ListView

```
android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="true"
```

`fastScrollEnabled` enables the dragging of the scroll bar.

Comment: Find no fastScrollEnabled in ScrollView !

Comment: i added these to my HorizontalScrollView, and see the scrollbar, yet it is not draggable

Comment: This solution is not working.