# scrollbar not working on touch android

Tags: android

I have scrollbars enabled on my recycler view but i am not able to scroll using that scroll.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:scrollbarSize="50dp"
        />
```

Something of this sort.

[image]

But that's just it, i can't hold the scroller and scroll down/up.

How do you make it scrollable? like i can touch and drag it down.

Update:

The question that has been tagged as duplicate for this one uses a list view.
I am using `recyclerview` and i don't see these two attributes provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254370/how-to-add-draggable-scrollbar-to-scrollview-listview-in-android).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add draggable scrollbar to scrollview/listview in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254370/how-to-add-draggable-scrollbar-to-scrollview-listview-in-android)

Comment: i can't get those two attributes in the recyler view?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` property to the RecyclerView if you are using a CoordinatorLayout and Toolbar along the RV.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, that you create a new layout file with your ***RecyclerView*** only:
`vertical_recycler_view.xml`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:scrollbarSize="50dp"/>
```

Now you can inflate and add the RecyclerView with scrollbars everywhere you want:
`MyCustomViewGroup.java`

```
public class MyCustomViewGroup extends FrameLayout
{
    public MyCustomViewGroup(Context context)
    {
        super(context);

        RecyclerView verticalRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.vertical_recycler_view, null);
        verticalRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        addView(verticalRecyclerView);
    }
}
```